# springboot use lua to create redis bloom filter : @user_script:1: ERR bad error rate

Tags: redis, lua, bloom-filter

I use the SpringBoot provided redistemplate to execute the Lua script:

```lua
return redis.call('bf.reserve', KEYS[1],ARGV[1],ARGV[2])
```

but it keeps getting wrong:

> ERR Error running script (call to f_264cca3824c7a277f5d3cf63f1b2642a0750e989): @user_script:1: ERR bad error rate.

this is my docker image:
redislabs/rebloom:2.2.5

i try to run this script in linux command,it works:

```
[root@daice ~]# redis-cli --eval a.lua city , 0.001 100000
OK
[root@daice ~]# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "city"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up the error in this [link](https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom/blob/master/src/rebloom.c), the snippet looks like

```
 if (RedisModule_StringToDouble(argv[2], &error_rate) != REDISMODULE_OK) {
        return RedisModule_ReplyWithError(ctx, "ERR bad error rate");
```

I assume the argument that you are providing for error_rate does not convert to a double value.